# aria-hidden="true" not hiding decendents from accessiblity checkers

Tags: html, image, wai-aria, alt

Most Accessibility checkers (eg WAVE) pick up that the image tag below does not have a alt attribute and flagging it as an error.
But the image tag is wrapped in a div with attribute aria-hidden="true". I was under the impression that aria-hidden="true" would hide all decedents  and ignore the image tag.

```
<div aria-hidden="true">
  <img src="my-image.png"/>
</div>
```

Am I right to assume the image should be hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is true that for user agents that support `aria-hidden` the `img` element will not be included in the accessibility tree, or will be flagged as hidden. But I am presuming that the checker is flagging it as an issue for UAs that do not support ARIA.

Suggest:

```
<img src="my-image.png" alt="">
```

By doing this you also won't get a [HTML conformance checking](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) error for not having an `alt` attribute :-)